# Paint color code between metallic water based and not water-based (Mayerling Green)

Tags: old-cars, chassis-paint

This should be a metallic water-based paint with color code ESB-MOSB, Mayerling green.

What I am trying to find out is if I can find the same color tone but just not as water-based, what would the color code then be called?

Not something I know, but assume that the difference between water-based and not water-based automatic gives a shade color difference, so if that's the case, what color code is the closest?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about the water based statement.  I don' know of any water based paints for automotive.  Even a little bit of water.

Comment: Do not know much about the topic, but the auto painter told me that it is water-based paint but should be correct.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - I thought *almost all automotive paints* used by manufacturers today are [water based](http://www.eastwood.com/water-based-paint-water-based-auto-automotive-car-paint)? In fact, isn't that all California will allow to be used? All in an effort to reduce VOC's?

Comment: This is in Europe and it can be? After what the painter told me it is the reason why it must ha clearcoat afterwards. But yes, more environmentally friendly.

Comment: Any good automotive paint seller can match the color in any type of paint you want.

Comment: Yes but would ask here, maybe I could get an answer here instead of calling and disturb a painter.